# Is there a way to retrieve unsaved files on visual studio code as they got deleted accidentally?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have accidentally clicked on "Delete all unsaved files" popup and this deleted all my unsaved files. Is there a way to retrieve these files?

I tried to check in the back up "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups" for those files and they don't show up in that location.